# Charles. Как установить ssl сертификат на iphone?

Tags: ios, mobile

Пытаюсь установить ssl сертификат на iphone для charles, чтобы перехватывать трафик, но сертификат не скачивается

шаги:

1. открываю мобильный safari/chrome
2. перехожу на официальный сайт www.charlesproxy.com/getssl

результат: открывается страница, но автоматического скачивания сертификата не происходит https://i.gyazo.com/2ab6955d9e5261c1434eb79a49ecf5...

в чем может быть проблема?

iphone 6
iOS 9.3.2

Comment: в safari открываете? в хроме скорее всего работать не будет

Comment: ну и это вы сделали уже https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/